# Could there be a meta-law that requires that a certain class of laws meet a certain property, and if they don't, they are immediately overrulled?

Tags: theory-of-law

When I wrote this, I immediately realized it sounds like a constitution, but there are ways in which what I have in mind is not how constitutions are conventionally designed (I think).

Here is an example. I saw a person taking an online anger management course on the behalf of someone else, who was court-ordered to take (and pass) it.

Let's say that I feel that the law is not well-designed, and that a person should not be ordered to do something which, as far as I can tell, may have no effect on their behavior (either because the course has no effect, or because they can "pass" it without taking it), when the purpose seems to be to enroll them in some kind of behavioral modification training.

What I see as an inefficient solution to this problem is to try to become an expert in anger management psychology and figure out which techniques may have some degree of efficacy; then advocate changes in legislation so that the new, better anger management course is what is required; and to also use research-backed course administration methodologies that ensure people actually comply with the course and are not cheating.

What I see as a more efficient solution to a general class of similar such problems is, you should not be able to pass a law which is demonstrably ineffective at attaining its purpose. If the purpose of the law is to reduce anger-motivated behaviors, then in the absence of evidence (with some strong standard, to be defined separately and determined also by a court, say) that it attains that purpose, a judge could immediately overrule a law that said that under certain circumstances, a person can be ordered to take that course.

The point is not anger management, but the broader question of "meta-laws". Is there any example of people creating some kind of meta-law which is meant to rigorously restrict laws themselves, based on some property they do or do not have? What interests me is that a society could enact a law that is "impartial" in some way, like, maybe a computer algorithm can run and determine if something meets a certain criteria; if it does not, the law says it is therefore illegal, even if the entire legislative body wants to vote it into law. (I.e., assuming there's a supreme court that uphods that meta-law.)

Comment: https://www.findlaw.com/legalblogs/law-and-life/challenging-laws-3-levels-of-scrutiny-explained/

Comment: *I saw a person taking an online anger management course on the behalf of someone else, who was court-ordered to take (and pass) it.* - in other words, you witnessed someone who was commiting fraud?

Comment: The list of laws with penalties that don't change behavior is likely extremely long.

Comment: I think this question would be better if it were more impersonal.  As is, there are many distracting details.